# What could be a reason for not finding a web element by its id?

Tags: selenium, robotframework, ui-automation

I have been using Robot Framework for a couple of days now to automate some basic flows tests in my working web app and found a problem:

> Can't find some web elements using the *id locator*

I've been using the *SeleniumLibrary* for this. Tried with different locators such as xPath and CSS selector, setting an implicit wait before looking for the element and the keywords `Wait Until Page Contains Element` and `Wait Until Element Is Visible`, but still it gives the same result.

First of all I check if a certain element is present:

`Page Should Contain Element  id=some-button`

then I try to send some keys to an input:

`Input Text  id=some-input  Some characters`

and then I get the error `Element with locator 'id=some-button' not found`

The page has the following structure:

```
...
<body>
  <div>
   ...
   <div>
    <form> 
     <div>
       <button id=some-button />
     </div>
     <div>
       <!--- 8 opening div tags -->
          <input id=some-input />
       <!--- 8 closing div tags -->
     </div>
    </form>    
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
...
```

Does any one have any idea why it happens?

UPDATE:

Tried

`/html/body/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/input`

instead of

`//*[@id="some-button"]`

and that worked perfectly.

Comment: Did you trying checking that the element is present before typing?

Comment: Running the keywords `Wait Until Element Is Visible` and `Wait Until Page Contains Element` also fails

Comment: Did you check to see if they are inside of an IFRAME?

Comment: There's no iframe element in the document.

Comment: please show the actual error message.

Comment: There, edited to show the error message, @BryanOakley

Answer (score 0):

> What could be a reason for not finding a web element by its id?

These are the reasons I can think of off the top of my head:

1. the element truly isn't on the page *at the time you're looking for it*. This could be because you aren't waiting for the page to finish rendering, or it could be that it's genuinely not there.
2. you could have a typo in the id
3. the element is in a frame
4. the element was there, but then got deleted by some executing javascript

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're using any Xpath or a CSS selector, you should always check in it in *Chrome Developer tools*. 

**Steps**:
 
1. Right click the page and click 'Inspect'
 
2. Go to Console tab
 
3. If it is a XPath evaluate using: $x and if it is a CSS selector, evaluate using $$

e.g.For 

Xpath:
`$x("//input[@id='Username']")`

CSS:
`$$("#Username")`

Comment: You can actually search in the inspector panel by css or xpath. Try it.